# What is the meaning of 大奥婚?

Tags: words, meaning

This headline in today's zakzak news, related to actress Miho Kanno getting married.

> 堺雅人＆菅野美穂、“大奥婚”！ 電撃ゴールイン

What is the meaning of 大奥婚? I know 大奥 and 婚 by themselves, but not together. I checked Space ALC website, but no results. Google search mostly pointed to this news, and other search engines were no help.

Comment: There was a TV drama called [大奥](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%A5%E3%80%9C%E8%AA%95%E7%94%9F%EF%BC%BB%E6%9C%89%E5%8A%9F%E3%83%BB%E5%AE%B6%E5%85%89%E7%AF%87%EF%BC%BD) in the recent past. 堺雅人 was the lead. Probably related to that.

Comment: 菅野美穂 was also in the 2012 and the 2003 dramas.

Comment: Whatever 大奥 refers to, 婚 is just short for 結婚.

Comment: So its like a contraction for 大奥 and 結婚, based on the fact they were both in the recent movie 「大奥 永遠」? Not sure why that didn't occur to me since I saw the movie recently.

Answer (score 4):

大奥婚 is made of two words:

- 大奥 most likely refers to the movie [『大奥〜永遠〜［右衛門佐・綱吉篇］』](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%A5%E3%80%9C%E6%B0%B8%E9%81%A0%E3%80%9C%EF%BC%BB%E5%8F%B3%E8%A1%9B%E9%96%80%E4%BD%90%E3%83%BB%E7%B6%B1%E5%90%89%E7%AF%87%EF%BC%BD).  As you can see from the Wikipedia link, both 堺雅人 and 菅野美穂 starred in this movie.
- 婚 is short for 結婚 ("wedding").

So you could translate it as "An Ōoku Wedding".